# Open ssh using ruby net/ssh with a specific port

Tags: ruby, ssh, port

I am trying to reflect the port as follows:

```
  Net::SSH.start( 'hostname', :username=>'', :password=>'', :port=>1234 ) do |session|      
     puts session.exec!('echo "hello"')
  end
```

But I am getting error:
Connection refused - connect(2) for 176.71.60.78:22 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

So according to the "22" in error, it seems for me that the port isnt reflected... Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I see docs in https://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net%2FSSH.start

```rb
.start(host, user = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

So

```rb
Net::SSH.start('hostname', '', { password: '', port: 1234 }) do |session|
  puts session.exec!('echo "hello"')
end
```

Comment: { password: '', port: 1234 } - this part is problematic, it says it wants "=>"

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
Net::SSH.start( 'host', 'username',  {:password => 'password',:port => 'port'}) do |session|      
 puts session.exec!('echo "hello"')
end
```